# Clang cross compilation in C

Tags: c, clang, cross-platform

I would like to cross compile my C code to other platforms, is there a way to cross compile it on everything ("everything" in here being everything that could support C), If my code is only using standard library headers?

(preferably I would like to not have to include any platform specific includes)

I tried compiling normal code using clang from linux to windows, but there were some problems
(
fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
#include <stdlib.h>
)

Comment: `stdlib.h` is not a platform-specific header.  Every conforming C implementation provides it.  It's unclear just how you attempted your cross compilation, but most likely your cross toolchain is not set up correctly.  Or maybe not set up at all.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: A lot of work. You need to have separate cross-compilers/build environments for each target architecture/environment. For example, just for x86, linux uses ELF object files and windows uses PE (portable executable) / COFF format object files. And, linux uses the amd64 ABI (application binary interface). The ABI specifies which reg gets which arg. windows has a different ABI that is not compatible. Then, for arm, you have various arm arches (e.g. cortex-M, cortex-A series). And (e.g.), linux, bare metal, FreeRTOS, etc OS environments. And, macOS, ios, android ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing a [mre] including the command lines how you try to compile and link your executables, and their diagnostic output. Additionally add what compiler packages you have installed and the OS you are using, please.